# Student is to answer 7 out of 10 questions in an examination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Student is to answer 7 out of 10 questions in
>   an examination. How
>   many if she must answer at least 3 of the first 5
>   questions?

**Credit:** A FIRST COURSE IN PROBABILITY - Sheldon Ross
University of Southern California

The answer is:
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{2}=110$$

Why my idea is not good?
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{7}{4}=350$$

I take 3 of 5 of the first questions, and then I have another 7 questions that I can answer and I choose 4. Thank you!

Comment: "How many if she must answer at least 3 of the first 5 questions?" - How many what??? And why are you mentioning that bold statement? Any reason why we need this irrelevant piece of information???

Comment: Your method over counts.  for example, you count the case in which she answers all five of the fist five questions many times.

Comment: Ths solution assumes that the student knows exactly $7$ answers out of $10$. Does she fail if she can answer more questions ?

Comment: After you have chosen questions from the first five, the rest must be from the last five. Otherwise you count combinations multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting those cases in which she answers four or five of the first five questions more than once.  You are counting them both among the $\binom{5}{3}$ selections of three of the first five questions and among the $\binom{7}{4}$ selections of four additional questions.

Suppose she answers four of the first five questions.  You have counted that case four times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways you could have selected three of those four questions as a member of the three questions that you selected from the first five.

Similarly, if she answers all five of the first five questions, you have counted that case $10$ times, once for each of the $\binom{5}{3}$ ways you could have selected three of those five questions as a member of the three questions that you selected from the first five.

Note that
$$\binom{3}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{2} = 350 = \binom{5}{3}\binom{7}{4}$$